# Invalid attempt to Read when reader is closed in c# from ms access

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I'm having an error to this code, I use winform to execute this code

Here's the cs code:

```
        try
        {

            conn5.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = conn5;
            string query = "select * from OrderDataListTable";
            command.CommandText = query;

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
               {
                    datetime = reader["DateTime"].ToString();
                    datetime = datetime.Substring(3, 2);
                    if (dateString == datetime)
                    {
                    String orderNum;    
                    orderNum = reader["OrderNo"].ToString();
                    textBox3.Text = orderNum.ToString();
                    conn5.Close();
                    getOrder();


                }
           }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }
```

The error Prompts with this certain code here:

```
while (reader.Read())
```

Comment: Adding error details here is helpful. Can you put `conn5.Close()` outside the while loop. You can close the connection after reading from the reader.

Comment: use **finally block** after **catch block** and put `conn5.Close()` in it

Comment: I tried it but its still giving me the same error.

Comment: @SylviaEspiña None of these answers didn't help you?

Answer (score 0):

I *strongly* suspect your `dateString == datetime` returns `true` when you read your reader and you close the connection while you read it. You can see it if you debug your code. You should not do that of course.

Reader *only* works when the connection is open.

I suggest to use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your command, connection and reader automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

```
using(var conn5 = new OleDbConnection(connString))
using(var command = conn5.CreateCommand())
{
      // Define your CommandText
      using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
      {
          while (reader.Read())
          {
               // Do other stuff
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By this command

```
while (reader.Read()) { .. }
```

the program goes through a loop of the rows being fetched by the reader. The reader is associated with a connection so by the command

```
conn.Close();
```

within the while statement causes only the first row to be read, close the connection causing not possible to read the others.

It will be a good practice to close the reader and connection on **finally** block when you use **try catch**.

Like this

```
    // Declare reader before the try block
    OleDbDataReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        conn5.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = conn5;
        string query = "select * from OrderDataListTable";
        command.CommandText = query;

        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
           {
                datetime = reader["DateTime"].ToString();
                datetime = datetime.Substring(3, 2);
                if (dateString == datetime)
                {
                String orderNum;    
                orderNum = reader["OrderNo"].ToString();
                textBox3.Text = orderNum.ToString();
                // conn5.Close();  -> remove this line
                getOrder();
           }
       }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
    }
    finally 
    {
        reader.Close();
        conn5.Close();
    }
```